# How to convert reader.readAsDataURL(file) to readAsArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, typescript, filereader

I have a component which allows me to drag multiple images onto the page and display the preview of those images. The following code achieves that:

```
displayPreviews(files: FileList) {

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

      const file = files.item(i);

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
          const image = reader.result as string;
          this.uploadFileArray.push({
            id: 'id',
            image: image,
          });
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      }
    }

----------

<li *ngFor="let image of uploadFileArray">
    <div *ngIf="image && image !== ''" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image.image  + ')'}"></div>
</li>
```

However, when selecting a large amount of images, it slows down the interaction with the rest of the page (form filling etc). I read that `reader.readAsArrayBuffer` can help alleviate that issue. However, I don't know how to integrate it. The below shows a grey box as it's no longer reading the image in the preview.

```
detectPhotos(files: FileList) {

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      // Reference to a file
      const file = files.item(i);

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
          const image = reader.result;

          this.uploadFileArray.push({
            id: 'id',
            image: image,
          });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      };
    
  }
```

Comment: I doubt it will matter how you load the images, the slowdown will be because -> `when selecting a large amount of images,`,  you will probably want to debounce / schedule the loading, rather than jus doing them all at once.

Comment: Thanks Keith. Do you have an example of how that would be achieved at all please? The UX at the moment is that the user can drop a bunch of images into a section of the page. It shows the previews of those images so that they can either choose to 'save' (saves to the db) or remove images from the array that they no longer want. So ideally, those images need to appear fairly quickly, which they do at the moment, but the rest of the page is slowed down a fair bit whilst typing.

Comment: There is possibly a bit of CPU overhead creating a DataURI, so you might be better using `URL.createObjectURL` to create the previews.   One thing to take into account if you do it this way, it's your responsibility to release the blobs with `URL.revokeObjectURL`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you have an example at all in regards to integrating it into my question code?

Comment: I'll see if I can knock up a quick snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue of using readAsDataURL, the browser is going to have to convert blob to dataURI and then to display it, it's having to decode the dataURI.  If you don't need to process the images first etc, you can use `URL.createObjectURL` to create a URL that references the BLOB instead.

Be aware, that `URL.createObjectURL` will keep the blob in memory until you call `URL.revokeObjectURL()`, it won't get GC'ed until you do.  If using something like React, you could attach this to a `useEffect` dismount, if using pure JS you will want to keep a reference of these to clear when your done.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  for (const file of e.target.files) {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.style.width = "100px";
    img.setAttribute('src', url);
    img.onload = () => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);     
    };
    document.querySelector('#images').appendChild(img);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="files" multiple accept="image/*"/>
<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time with that, Keith. On first implementation, this works a treat. The previews display and the form doesn't freeze up. The only issue I have no is that my compressorJs resize function no longer works because it's expecting a file or blob. I'm using Angular, I'm not sure how to use the `revokeObjectURL` there yet.

Comment: Update: ` let blob = await fetch(this.file).then(r => r.blob());` seems to do the trick with the resizing stuff. Just need to figure out how to use revokeObjectURL now!

Comment: The images are passed to a child component which when displayed, begins uploading them. I pass the files into that (which is essentially blob: localhost/jhskjdhkasdsa). If I were to do `URL.revokeObjectURL(this.file);` after the image uploads, is there a way to tell if that has worked successfully?

Comment: @Que  You could maybe just revoke it as soon as the image has loaded into the img tag, it doesn't seem to cause any issues,  I've updated my snippet to do this.  Also your original blob should still work, just keep a reference to it, you shouldn't need to fetch.

Comment: @Que Just had an idea for you.   If you don't revoke straight away,  you could possibly use a webworkers to do your scaling for you, it's a bit more complex to implement, but one advantage of an ObjectURL you should be able to share it with multiple webWorkers ..

Comment: Thanks Keith. I'm using angular, so I'm passing an array of images to a child component, opposed to creating an img tag via JS. I'm essentially doing the same as my code in my post, minus the reader. I'm pushing the url from 'createObjectURL` into the array. In the child component I revokeObjectURL. Not entirely sure how to check that works though!

Comment: You can check if it's worked by trying the blob url into another tab, if it's revoked it should not display, if it displays then you have not revoked..

Comment: Yup, I thought of that, but as the URL is along the lines of `http://localhost:4200/260c2763-22f8-47e0-852e-879f2fe0ccd9`, it just opens the angular component based on the routing fall back. Based on that, I can't actually see if it exists or not.

Comment: The URL should be more like -. `blob:null/260c2763-22f8-47e0-852e-879f2fe0ccd9`

Comment: Doh! - It did actually work, I just omitted the `blob:` prefix. I think it's all working. Keith, you have been awesome. Thank you for your time. Greatly appreciated.